# How to use fscanf() to read a file containing integer number?

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I need to use `fscanf()` to read a file containing integers from multiple lines.

The first integer is useless on every line; the rest I need to read.

I am doing like this

```
do {
    fscanf(fs1[0],"%d%c",&x,&y);
    //y=fgetc(fs1[0]);
    if(y!='\n') {
        printf("%d ",x);  
    }
} while(!feof(fs1[0]));
```

but in vain. For example,

```
101 8 5 
102 10 
103 9 3 5 6 2 
104 2 6 3 8 7 5 4 9 
105 8 7 2 9 10 3 
106 10 6 5 4 2 3 9 8 
107 3 8 10 4 2
```

we have to read

```
8 5
10
9 3 5 6 2 
2 6 3 8 7 5 4 9
8 7 2 9 10 3
10 6 5 4 2 3 9 8
3 8 10 4 2
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the file contains a new line character at the end? Files can contain `\r` or `\n` or `\r\n` for end of line.

Answer (score 2):

AFTER you have read file in a string, (**fgets**)
you can use **(strtok)**, to split string and then use 
**(sscanf)** to read  integer.

**strtok** :

```
char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
char * pch;
printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
while (pch != NULL)  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
}
```

**sscanf** :

```
int number = 0;
if(sscanf(pch, "%d", &number) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `fgets()` to read the file line by line and then parse the numbers using `sscanf()`. You can then skip the first number for each line just as you please.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char fname[] = "filename.txt";
    char buf[256];
    char *p;
    /* open file for reading */
    FILE * f = fopen(fname, "r");
    /* read the file line-wise */
    while(p = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f)) {
        int x, i = 0, n = 0;
        /* extract numbers from line */
        while (sscanf(p+=n, "%d%n", &x, &n) > 0)
            /* skip the first, print the rest */
            if (i++ > 0)
                printf("%d ", x);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

For reference:

- http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets
- http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf

Answer (score 0):

```
    do{
        fscanf(fs1[0], "%d%c",&x,&y);//ignore first data.
        while(2==fscanf(fs1[0], "%d%c", &x, &y)){
            printf("%d ", x);
            ch = fgetc(fs1[0]);//int ch;
            if(ch == '\n' || ch == EOF){
                printf("\n");
                break;
            } else
                ungetc(ch, fs1[0]);
        }
    }while(!feof(fs1[0]));
```